# android retrolambda, statement lambda can be replaced with expression lambda

Tags: android, android-studio, lambda, retrolambda

I use retrolambda in my project, it works great. but today when i used it, Android Studio give me a tip:

[image]

I haven't seen this before, how I need to modify the code in order to meet this tip.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `return` statement is not needed for single-line expressions, so it's telling you that it's safe to delete (hence why return is grayed out).  For example, you can refactor that to:

`player.setOnErrorListner((mp, what, extra) -> true);`